# Rights When Terminated Without Fair Process

Tags: united-kingdom, termination, employees, employment-agreement

A friend has just been dismissed from her job for "not being good enough."

This fell on her out of the blue, with no prior warning, no development or action plan, and no notice period. Apparently the CEO fired her directly, without going through her manager.

She has worked with them since May of last year so she is not eligible to claim unfair dismissal, and she is not unionised, but she *was* outside of her probation period and was a full time worker on a permanent contract. She was employed in the UK and is a British citizen.

Are there any other avenues to pursue if she has been dismissed in violation of her employer’s internal disciplinary processes?

Comment: We won't be able to help you here, since we don't know nearly enough about the case. I assume your friend asked why she was dismissed and did not get a satisfactory answer. At this point, it seems like she can only go talk to a lawyer.

Comment: Thanks @StephanKolassa, I don't know a huge amount at this point myself. She'll likely have to go a lawyer, I was just hoping that there may be a law regarding contract violation I'd not managed to find on Google :)

Comment: You won't find her employment contract on Google.

Comment: She needs a competent lawyer and her contract. And ideally any relevant company handbook/procedures.

Comment: We've got the contract, so that leaves a lawyer I guess. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a lawyer but according to 
http://www.adviceguide.org.uk/wales/work_w/work_rights_at_work_e/basic_rights_at_work.htm#h_how_much_notice_should_you_get
unless she was fired for gross misconduct she should have been entitled to one week's notice or pay in lieu.

Other than that, I don't think she's entitled to anything as she was less than a year there.

Comment: Yeah, this is where I ended up as well :( Figured it was a long shot to find any other rules I'd missed. Thanks